# Android/Java Singleton with HashMap not keeping HashMap values

Tags: java, android

I'm using a Singleton to store a cache of objects but whenever I call the Singleton and add to the `HashMap`, it has no values.

The cache is checked at the beginning of a method (when the size is 1) but when adding to the `HashMap` again, the size of it is 0. The size of it therefore alternates between 0 and 1.

```
public class CachedObjects
{
    static HashMap<String, Object> cachedObjects = new HashMap<>();

    private static class InstanceHolder
    {
        private static final CachedObjects instance = new CachedObjects();
    }

    public static CachedObjects getInstance()
    {
        return CachedObjects.InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    public void addObjectToCache(Object object)
    {
        cachedObjects.put(object.getTitle(), object);
    }

    public Object checkCacheForObject(String title)
    {
        Iterator it = cachedObjects.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            if (pair.getKey().equals(title))
            {
                return (Object) pair.getValue();
            }
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where it's called:

```
public Object getObjectInfoFrom(String title)
    {
        Object cachedObjectCheck = CachedObjects.getInstance().checkCacheForObject(title);
        // Size of HashMap is usually 1 here

        if (cachedObjectCheck != null)
        {
            return cachedObjectCheck ;
        }

        // Lots of DB fetching here

        Object object = new Object(DB details above);
        CachedObjects.getInstance().addObjectToCache(object);
        // The size of the HashMap always seems to be empty here

        return object;
    }
```

Comment: You need to synchronise access to the map. Read the javadoc for hashmap, the relevant bit is in bold at the top.

Comment: 1) Don't implement a singleton, they are evil. If you have to rely on one use the pseudo singletons provided by the Android framework - like the `Application` object. 2) Your code doesn't make sense. The `InstanceHolder` class has no purpose whatsoever and your code is overly complicated. 3) I would be careful about memory leaks,  I can't see all the critical pieces of code which might cause memory leaks, but the structure of your code surely looks like a memory leak might be right around the corner.

Comment: @XaverKapeller whats the problem about singletons?

Comment: @Xaver the `InstanceHolder` class provides thread safe lazy instantiation of the singleton https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom. It doesn't serve no purpose.

Comment: @Vyacheslav What isn't? They are monolythic, static god objects, that by their very nature force themselves right into every part of your app, they increase coupling as well as code complexity, decrease maintainability, and completely ruin any chances of properly testing your project. They are not required and make everything more complicated. The actual use cases for Singletons are so incredibly rare and specific, hardly any developers will ever have a legitimate case for using them - and certainly no reputable app developer would use them - they go against every modern design principle.

Comment: you know that checkCacheForObject removes all items until it find the search one every time it is called? maybe you do not understand your own code ...

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes I realize that, but what purpose does this serve for you? You know that this doesn't make your `HashMap` suddenly thread safe, right? And `it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException` certainly doesn't avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` - it can cause it since you are removing elements from the `Map`. And having said that you are removing elements from the `Map` in a method which is just supposed to check if an element exists. Why? Might that be the problem? **hint hint**

Comment: Enjoyed reading your debate, guys.

Yes, the problem was with `it.remove()`. That's what happens when I copy and paste code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyContext {
    private static MyContext ourInstance = null;
    private HashMap<String, String> translatedValue;

    public static MyContext getInstance() {
        if (ourInstance == null)
            ourInstance = new MyContext();
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private MyContext() {
        translatedValue = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addTranslatedValue(String title, String value) {
        translatedValue.put(title, value);
    }

    public String getTranslatedValue(String value) {
        return translatedValue.get(value);
    }
}
```

Using

```
MyContext.getInstance().addTranslatedValue("Next", valueTranslated);
System.out.println(myContext.getTranslatedValue("Next"));
```

Result

```
valueTranslated
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is not singleton because you have not hidden the constructor.
second, you need to remove this line:

```
it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
```

Try this code, it works OK:

```
    private static CachedObjectsClass singletonInstance = null;

    HashMap<String, Object> cachedObjects;

    private CachedObjectsClass()
    {
        cachedObjects = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static CachedObjectsClass getInstance()
    {
        singletonInstance = singletonInstance == null ? new CachedObjectsClass()
                : singletonInstance;
        return singletonInstance;
    }

    public void addObjectToCache(String key, Object object)
    {
        cachedObjects.put(key, object);
    }

    public Object checkCacheForObject(String title)
    {
        return cachedObjects.get(title);
    }
```

And usage:

```
    Object cachedObjectCheck = CachedObjectsClass.getInstance()
                .checkCacheForObject("kk");

    CachedObjectsClass.getInstance().addObjectToCache("l", object);
```